# EEVEE Render fail

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

1. When I press Ctrl + F12 to render sequence, it renders only the first frame and Blender closes.
2. When I created new blend file and copy pasted all contents, it rendered all frames fine, only once. Now if I try to render all again, it crashes too.

**3. Now when I repeat step 2 - make another new file, copy paste, it crashes like the first time (second method doesnt work anymore)**

I am using Blender 3.0. I am trying as hard as possible to remember what I did before crashing happneed, but rn all i can remember is that I tried changing render from JPEG to AVI JPEG, with quality from default setting (90%) to 100%. When I try other render types like PNG, still crashes.

I am so lost, I can't figure out where I messed up and really cant figure out where to elaborate on more so I'm posting the files from step 1 and 2.

### Some of the things I tried were

1. Redownloading Blender 3.0
2. Trying on 2.9, but rigs done on 3.0 gets messed up when opened in 2.9, so doesnt work
3. Lowering frame range - Rendered from 1-200 and crashed, so changed to 1-10, still crashed

This is the original file that crashed,
[image]

This is the newer file that rendered first time and crashed. [image]

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: +++ Rendering frame by frame is working.

Comment: After I change Collisions (football-Solid.001) from Convex Hull to Sphere and Render Animation seem work fine.